# Complex Json Deserialization in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a json format that looks like the following and I wish to deserialize it with python using import json

```
{
    "FATHERFIELD 1": [
       {
         "childfield 1":[
         ],
         "childfield 2": [
             {
                 "a": 1,
                 "b": 2,
                 "c": {
                     "c_1": 3
                 }
             }
         ]
       }
    ],
    "FATHERFIELD 2": [
     ]
}
```

In python, how would one use the json.loads() function to call the respective fields? Specifically, if I used

```
foo = json.loads(childfield2)
```

what kind of object would this be in python?

Comment: JSON syntax is almost a subset of Python syntax. Do you know what Python data structure the JSON looks like? (If you don't, you should probably go through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), because you're missing a ton of important background knowledge.)

Answer (score 2):

You have *one JSON document*; you'd either read that document into a Python string (from a file or network connection) or open a file object for JSON data stored on disk, and decode it using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). `json.loads()` decodes JSON data from a string, `json.load()` does so from a file object.

Once loaded, you have a Python object; a dictionary containing other objects, including more dictionaries and lists. You'd address these like any other Python object:

```
dict_from_json['FATHERFIELD 1'][0]['childfield 1']
```

addresses a key in the first dictionary in the list addressed by the `'FATHERFIELD 1'` key in the top-level dictionary.

Answer (score -4):

```
import json
myfamily = {
  "child1" : {
    "name" : "Emil",
    "year" : 2004,"
  },
  "child2" : {
    "name" : "Tobias",
    "year" : 2007
  },
  "child3" : {
    "name" : "Linus",
    "year" : 2011
  }
}

print(json.myfamily)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.